# Hyperbolic plane shrinking

Tags: euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

A very small area of the hyperbolic plane looks more Euclidean as the curvature approachs 0.
Any more evidence?
Or reference would help?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please clarify: 1. Are you shrinking a piece of a fixed hyperbolic space, or taking hyperbolic spaces that are successively flat? 2. In what form have you encountered hyperbolic space? What does "looking more Euclidean" mean to you? 3. What type of evidence are you seeking? (Geometric, analytic, ....) Thanks! :)

Comment: When we take a small piece of a general hyperbolic plane. For example, a very small triangle where its area approachs 0. From Gauss-Bonnet theorem, the sum of its angles approachs $pi$. I mean the geometry converge to the Euclidean one. Any more geometric or analytic evidence?

Comment: There is a difference between "curvature approaches 0" in your question and "area approaches 0" in your comment. Perhaps you could clear this up?

Comment: Just thinking, when we look at a very small hyperbolic area, it seems more flat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those things where as you learn more about non-euclidean geometry the "evidence" just accumulates. The distance formula is
$$ds^2=\cosh^2 y dx^2+dy^2$$ and we see that $\cosh y\to 1$ as $y\to 0$ another formula is the pythagorean formula $\cosh c=\cosh a\cosh b$ limits to $c^2=a^2+b^2$ for small $a$ and $b$. Good refs are Carslaw, and Hartshorne's excellent "Euclid and beyond".